# Missing polygon when baking in Cycle render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, uv, texture-baking

I'm trying to bake my character for unity but only some polygons' materials were baked. The body isn't showing up :(

I am using cycle render and assigned different materials to different polygons.

Please see attached screenshot for clarification. Thank you, really appreciate any help!

Agatha

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Got it. my body's normal was inverted. Didn't realise that was the problem until I baked the texture on a transparent image - showing the polygons as black.